# Print in real time without waiting for the script to complete in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to run external script(demo_print.py) and print the output in real time.
But it doesn't work for me. The program wait until the script end print all output.
My goal is Print in real time without waiting for the script to complete. How to fix it ?
0
1
2
....
9

**demo_print.py**

```
import time
for i in range(10):
  print(f"print {i}")
  time.sleep(1)
```

**main.py**

```
def run_command(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        output = process.stdout.readline()
        if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
            break
        if output:
            print(output.decode('UTF-8').strip())
    rc = process.poll()
    return rc 

def main(argv):
    cmd = "demo_print.py"
    run_command(cmd)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: print("...", flush=True)

Comment: didn't help @amirhm